# Android Status Bar Color

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments

I am having problem with status bar color when I use `android:fitsSystemWindows="false"`

It becomes transparent. I dont want that to happen. I want to it have `colorPrimaryDark` as its color.

I have to set this as `false` because I am using a `FrameLayout` in main layout so that I can inflate a overlay fragment, When `android:fitsSystemWindows="false"` is set `true` the overlay occupies whole screen, I dont want that to happen with overlay fragment.

my activity_main looks like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:background="@drawable/layout_bg_white"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
tools:openDrawer="start"
tools:context="com.example.tabstrial2.MainActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_layout_of_app"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">




</RelativeLayout>


<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/overlay_fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="56dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="119dp" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

style.xml looks like this.

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">#500347</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#862b7b</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#1a2fcf</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">#fff</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@android:color/holo_green_dark</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#fff</item>   <!-- normal border color      change as you wish -->
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">#500347</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"      parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

<style name="AppTheme.Picker" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
</style>

<!--<style name="AppTheme.CheckBox" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">-->
<!--<item name="android:colorAccent">@android:color/white</item>-->
<!--</style>-->

<style name="MyCheckBox" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#fff
    </item>   <!-- normal border color change as you wish -->
    <item name="colorControlActivated">#fff</item> <!-- activated color change as you wish -->
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFF3F3C</item> <!-- checkbox text color -->
</style>
```

Comment: show your theme used for the activity

Comment: @MujammilAhamed , Added style.xml in Question, please have a look.

Comment: just follow this tutorial (http://www.androidhive.info/2015/04/android-getting-started-with-material-design/ ), may be it will help you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Activity below the setcontentview(...)

```
Window window = getWindow();
window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
// finally change the color
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    window.setStatusBarColor(Color.parseColor("#c2212a"));
}
```

Comment: Thanks. What will happen if android version is less than LOLLIPOP? what will be color of status bar then? Sorry I would have checked myself, but I cant run emulator on my PC configuration.

Comment: @BhushanBabar try to install emulator working with LOLLIPOP+, and if the version is less then LOLLIPOP the color will be black, the default color.

Comment: thanks for sharing @Ali Taouni .. i checked many answers this is very clear one .. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42968587/android-email-client-receiver-email-id-empty-in-android-parse  please check this if you can

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set the status bar color explicit

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/color_primary_dark</item>
```

or set the translucent status to false

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">false</item>
```

Comment: try `<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">false</item>`

Comment: Nope, again its valid only above 19 API. Ali Taouni's answer worked for me.